# Conjugate symmetric: 3D Fourier transform dimension

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, dft

I have a real-valued input 3D array with the shape of `(H,W,D)=[8,8,20]`, where H, W, and D represent height, width and depth(z dimension), respectively. When computing the DFT, what will be the dimension of the DFT complex array (3D Fourier Transform)?

I read in one article that 2D DFT becomes like the following due to the conjugate symmetry:

[image]

For 2D arrays of real value with `(H,W): [8,8]`, the dimension of DFT becomes `[8, 8//2+1] = [8, 5]`. In the case of 3D input real array, what will be the DFT array size?

Comment: Posted my previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real-valued input, about half the values in the DFT are redundant because of the Hermitian symmetric property. The n-dimensional DFT tensor could omit half of any dimension. For example, PyTorch's  [`torch.fft.rfftn`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.fft.rfftn.html) omits half the length of the final dimension producing a tensor of size `[D1, D2, ..., DN//2 + 1]`.